# jQuery Datatables: Ajax vs c# loading

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, datatables

Finally got datatables to properly retrieve, then format data for an application I am writing and after looking at the code, I began to wonder, is it better to allow datatables to retrieve the raw data and format it in the javascript of the view, or format the table data in a class before it's handed back to datatables?

My first instinct would to be to allow the class to do it, but, being new to jQuery, I was wondering if that WAS the way, then why would datatables have that much client side capability.

Anyone have pros or cons for either way?

Comment: When you say "format," are your referring to manipulating the data or adding some type of styling?

Comment: @Kent - Not necessarily changing data, but items like adding styling to the cell, combining two fields data into one cell, changing styling based on the value of a cell, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more, I would recommend formatting and styling on the client side.
Here are a few thoughts...

- With a website/client app, reducing the amount of traffic / data sent to the client from the server will be beneficial.
- Centralizing the logic for any styling will benefit you in the long term by reducing the complexity of your site and make it easier to change later.
- Styling on the client-side will allow you to serve multiple different types of clients with the same server-side code (ie: native mobile app and web browsers).
- Common practice is to provide the data you wish to have displayed in a standard format such as JSON, then format the content to fit the client device in the client-side code.

Comment: Thanks.  I am passing the un-markedup data as a JSON string and then making it "pretty" on the client side.